# how can we hide a button in a view when it first appears and later it should appear 

Tags: iphone, ios

I am using a Done button in my first view controller . when application opens , the  Done button should be hidden .but when the user goes to second view controller, I am pushing the second view controller to first view again and then I want to show the Done button in my first view Controller.

How can I do this?

Comment: u want done button on first view or on second view?

Comment: are you pushing from the second controller or popping from it ?

Comment: @shashank i have two class in first class i want to hide done button when it appears first time and when i go to second class and from there when i push the second class tableview to first-class  the done button should get appear in first-class  i am pushing the view with navigation controller but navigation controller is not visible in first class

Answer (score 1):

Make an IBOutlet of the Button, Like IBOutlet UIButton *doneButton; Connect this IBOutlet doneButton to the Button

In ViewDidLoad [doneButton setHidden:YES];

At place where you are Presenting second view controller, you can make it Visible like 
[doneButton setHidden:NO];

I think you want button on navigationBar
So add button to navigationBar use this

```
 UIBarButtonItem *doneNavigationBarButton = [[UIBarButtonItem alloc] initWithTitle:@"Tool" style:UIBarButtonItemStylePlain target:self action:@selector(doneNavigationBarButtonClicked)];
[[self navigationItem] setRightBarButtonItem: doneNavigationBarButton];
[doneNavigationBarButton release];

And make a method 
- (void)doneNavigationBarButtonClicked
{   NSLog(@"Done button Clicked");
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Make a BOOL Property `isDoneVisible` in your first controller and set it to NO in your `viewDidLoad`. while pushing from first controller, set its value to Yes and in your `viewWill Appear`:

```
if(isDoneVisible==YES)
{    
 [DoneButton setHidden:NO];
}
else
{
[DoneButton setHidden:YES];
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Take one Bool variable and then check if that variable is yes then show your button else hide it.

Comment: thanks for the reply I used what you replied but its not working

Answer (score 0):

In viewDidload, set the property `[button setHidden:YES];`

In viewWillAppear, set the property `[button setHidden:NO];`